# Is there a max number of unicast messages in 802.11p?

Tags: veins, vehicle-routing, 802.11p

How many vehicles could send a unicast message to a road side unit at the same time? Is there a limit?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending is not the problem, receiving is. The simulation model takes care of representing the real-life limitation of typical WLAN receivers only being able to receive one message at the same time.